# How to combine multiple Mockito matchers with a logical "and"/"or"?

Tags: mockito

I'd like to verify using Mockito that a string argument satisfies two conditions:

```
verify(mockClass).doSomething(Matchers.startsWith("prefix"));
verify(mockClass).doSomething(Matchers.endsWith("suffix"));
```

How to combine those two into one statement?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is possible using `org.mockito.AdditionalMatchers`:

```java
import static org.mockito.AdditionalMatchers.and;

verify(mockClass).doSomething(
         and(Matchers.startsWith("prefix"), 
             Matchers.endsWith("suffix"));
```

There are also `org.mockito.AdditionalMatchers.or` and `org.mockito.AdditionalMatchers.not`.

Comment: What package `and` is in ? I can't find it.

Comment: @expert `import static org.mockito.AdditionalMatchers.and;`

Comment: Is there a corresponding matcher for 3 or more arguments?

Comment: You can write your own utility method if you want to support an arbitrary number of arguments. Using Java 8: `@SafeVarargs public static <T> T and(T... matchers) { return stream(matchers).reduce(argThat(any -> true), AdditionalMatchers::and); }`

Comment: @neXus I like it, actually it's `@SafeVarargs public static <T> T and(T... matchers) { return Stream.of(matchers).reduce(argThat(any -> true), AdditionalMatchers::and); }` though

Comment: I meant `java.util.Arrays.stream(T[])` which actually does the same as `java.util.stream.Stream.of(T...)`. I personally prefer using the `Arrays.stream` when I have an actual array, and using `Stream.of` when I have multiple separate objects. When using `Stream.of` with a single array as argument there's always the tiniest bit of confusion about whether it's creating a `Stream<T>` over all elements in the array or a `Stream<T[]>` of a single element (the array itself)

Answer (score 1):

Prior comments have called out that `and` takes only two arguments, and that having a variant that takes three or more would be advantageous. The following code solves this recursively, allowing multiple matchers to be specified in varargs:

```
public static String conjunction(String... matchers) {
  if (matchers.length < 2) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("matchers.length must be >= 2");
  } else if (matchers.length == 2) {
    return and(matchers[0], matchers[1]);
  } else {
    final String[] tail = new String[matchers.length - 1];
    System.arraycopy(matchers, 1, tail, 0, tail.length);
    return and(matchers[0], conjunction(tail));
  }
}
```

assuming the following imports:

```
import static org.mockito.AdditionalMatchers.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
```

Comment: Using Java 8, working for any type and for any number of arguments: `@SafeVarargs public static <T> T and(T... matchers) { return stream(matchers).reduce(argThat(any -> true), AdditionalMatchers::and); }`