# Again How to combine multiple mockito OngoingStubbing with a logical “and”/“or”?

Tags: java, mockito

I do some arrangement when testing with mockito like this:

```
private void serviceCallSuccess() {
    when(mTmdbWebService.highestRatedMovies()).thenReturn("abc");
    when(mTmdbWebService.newestMovies()).thenReturn("abc");
    when(mTmdbWebService.popularMovies()).thenReturn("abc");
}
```

And they did work, however the code is so lengthy. I want to 
combine these above arrangement for cleaner test. Something like this:

```
when(
     mTmdbWebService.highestRatedMovies()
     OR mTmdbWebService.newestMovies()
     OR mTmdbWebService.popularMovies()
     ).thenReturn("abc");
```

I found some code here about combining functions in .thenReturn but it is not exactly what I need. 
 [How to combine multiple Mockito matchers with a logical "and"/"or"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22527469/how-to-combine-multiple-mockito-matchers-with-a-logical-and-or)

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to define your own default behavior for the mock:

```
List<String> methodsToMock =
    Arrays.asList("highestRatedMovies", "newestMovies", "popularMovies");

mTmdbWebService = mock(TmdbWebService.class, invocationOnMock -> {
    Method mockedMethod = invocationOnMock.getMethod();
    if (methodsToMock.contains(mockedMethod.getName()) &&                
        mockedMethod.getParameterCount() == 0 &&
        mockedMethod.getReturnType().equals(String.class)) {
        return "abc";
    }
    return null;
});
```